# Open HDF5 files in Julia

Tags: julia, hdf5

I have Julia 1.7.2 and HDF v"0.16.2" on a Windows 10 machine.
I ran into an issue opening an HDF5 file:

```
using HDF5
raw_hdf_data = h5open("Data_2021-03-17_11-21-19.h5", "r")  
obj = raw_hdf_data["Group"]["Data_1"]
HDF5.read(obj)
```

but got an error:

> HDF5.API.H5Error: Error reading dataset /Flatfield/Data_1
> libhdf5 Stacktrace:
> [1] H5PL__find_plugin_in_path: Plugin for dynamically
> loaded library/Can't open directory or file
> can't open directory
> ⋮
> [11] H5Dread: Dataset/Read failed
> can't read data
>
> Stacktrace:
> [1] macro expansion
> @ C:\Users\jhsu.julia\packages\HDF5\auFb7\src\api\error.jl:18 [inlined]
> [2] h5d_read(dataset_id::HDF5.Dataset,
> mem_type_id::HDF5.Datatype, mem_space_id::HDF5.Dataspace,
> file_space_id::HDF5.Dataspace,
> xfer_plist_id::HDF5.DatasetTransferProperties, buf::Matrix{Int64})
> @ HDF5.API C:\Users\jhsu.julia\packages\HDF5\auFb7\src\api\functions.jl:508
>
> [3] generic_read(::HDF5.Dataset, ::HDF5.Datatype, ::Type{Int64})
> @ HDF5 C:\Users\jhsu.julia\packages\HDF5\auFb7\src\HDF5.jl:978
> [4] read(obj::HDF5.Dataset)
> @ HDF5 C:\Users\jhsu.julia\packages\HDF5\auFb7\src\HDF5.jl:878
> [5] (::var"#66#67")(fid::HDF5.File)
> @ Main .\In[68]:3
> [6] h5open(::var"#66#67", ::String, ::Vararg{String, N} where N; swmr::Bool,
> pv::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(),
> Tuple{}}})
> @ HDF5 C:\Users\jhsu.julia\packages\HDF5\auFb7\src\HDF5.jl:287
> [7] h5open(::Function, ::String, ::String)
> @ HDF5 C:\Users\jhsu.julia\packages\HDF5\auFb7\src\HDF5.jl:285
> [8] top-level scope
> @ In[68]:1
> [9] eval
> @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
> [10] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module,
> code::String, filename::String)
> @ Base .\loading.jl:1116

Thanks very much!

Comment: The error message is unclear whether it can't find a plugin or just can't find the file itself. Can you do a ls on the current directory (```;ls``` or `run(\`ls\`)`) and verify that the file you are trying to open is returned in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I updated my HDF5 library.
Probably the file is compressed and one of the following plugins are necessary. Try:

```
] add H5Zblosc, H5Zbzip2, H5Zlz4, H5Zzstd
using HDF5, H5Zblosc, H5Zbzip2, H5Zlz4, H5Zzstd
raw_hdf_data = h5open("Data_2021-03-17_11-21-19.h5", "r")  
...
```

Now it should open the file.